# How to use guice dependency injection in Play tests (Play 2.6.3)

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I have a test specification called MyTestSpec. The aim it is to test a controller that uses dependency injection in its constructor.

```
class StatusController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, counter: Counter) extends AbstractController(cc) { ...
```

The Counter class is another controller that provides a status over to the other. When I now try to test this controller, I have the option to either mock the required Counter class, construct the whole chain of controllers / dependencies or inject it. Let's ignore mocking for now, although it probably would be the more correct thing to do.

The issue is that always when I try to inject the Counter controller, I get a NullPointerException.

What I tried so far:

- Inject the Counter into the constructor of MyTestSpec, but then MyTestSpec won't even be constructed and tested.
- Inject into a local var with the @Inject annotation.
- Inject into a val via app.injector.instanceOf[Counter].
- Inject via the shortform inject[Counter].

All don't actually give me this other Controller.

Below a rough outline of the test, the new application to get started with Play can be easily adjusted to demonstrate the issue:

```
class MyTestSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest with Injecting {
  "StatusController GET" should {
    "render the status page from a new instance of controller" in {
      val controller = new StatusController(stubControllerComponents(), counter)
      ...
  }
}
```

The question: is there a way to simply inject this Counter controller? If there is no simple way, the follow on question would be what components I can then inject anyway if I am already being restrained... ?

**Note:** this is different to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972670/unit-testing-a-controller-in-play-2-6), although I tried the solution provided in it.

**Note 2:** thank you to the Play and ScalaTest developers as well as all these contributors behind the scenes - a wonderful framework.

Comment: Maybe you have a circular dependency in the other Controller?

Comment: What you can also try is to replace `Counter` with an Interface Trait, bind your `StatusController` to that trait, as they are much easier to mock. `Counter` of course still have to implement it (for that you can have a look at the `implementedBy`-Annotation)

Comment: Where exactly did you get that NullPointerException? How exactly did you setup the dependency? Have you considered obtaining an instance of `StatusController` via the injector in your test?

Comment: @nob No circular dependencies.

Comment: @rethab Interestingly, I got the exception when trying to access the app object via app.injector.instanceOf for example. This has now led me to replace the GuiceOneAppPerTest trait with GuiceOneAppPerSuite trait and it works. I will check if this might be a bug.

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/issues/107